# node.js graphql/sequelize server returns null for linked properties

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, graphql-js

I have a node.js server that uses sequelize and graphql to provide GraphQL endpoint.

Somehow object fields that are linked with `belongsTo` are always `null` in GraphQL query output.

Here are my graphql typedefs:

```
type Student {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  age: Int!
  schoolClass: SchoolClass
}

type SchoolClass {
  id: ID!
  title: String!
}
```

Here is how sequelize model defined

```
const SchoolClass = sequelize.define('SchoolClass', {
  title: Sequelize.STRING
});

const Student = sequelize.define('Student', {
  name: Sequelize.STRING,
  age: Sequelize.TINYINT
});

Student.belongsTo(SchoolClass);
```

The resolver is

```
students (root, args, context) {
    return models.Student.findAll({}, context);
}
```

The query:

```
{ 
  students { 
    id, name, age, schoolClass { id } 
  } 
}
```

Typical output:

```
{
  "data": {
    "students": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "John",
        "age": "18",
        "schoolClass": null
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Is there any way to get actual data instead of nulls?

Comment: does Student table has class_id/classId ?

Comment: @VivekDoshi yes, it has SchoolClassId field with appropriate IDs filled in
(I renamed Class to SchoolClass not to confuse this entity with JS Class)

Comment: Check this out  : https://github.com/mickhansen/graphql-sequelize , think this will help you

Answer (score 2):

By default, Sequelize does not populate any fields created by relationships when calling `findAll`. You have to use the `include` option to specify which relationships you want to include the query. See [the docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/models-usage.html#eager-loading) for more info.

Additionally, `findAll` only takes one argument (an options object), and I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do by passing your context to the model. This should be sufficient to get all Students with their associated schoolClass:

```
return models.Student.findAll({ include: [ 'SchoolClass' ] })
```

[Check out the reference](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-findAll) for `findAll` for more info about what options you can use.

Comment: The problem was outside the code I pasted here, it was in graphql resolver. `return` was missing in the function
  Student: {
    class(student) {
      student.getClass();
    }
  }